# Errors deploying working SAPUI5 (Web IDE) app to SCP Fiori Launchpad

Tags: sapui5, sap-web-ide

I can run this as a web application, but when I deploy to SAP Cloud Platform, then register to SCP Fiori Dashboard, I get errors.

Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: This also works correctly when Run as "SAP Fiori Launchpad Sandox".

Comment: Only when access through the portal when I'm receiving errors.

Comment: Try activating the SICF service

Comment: Please check the tile configuration. “ManageCategories/ManageCategories/Component.js” looks a bit strange.